# Solr doesn't start and log file is getting deleted

Tags: solr

solr-5.4.0 version

My Java version

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)
```

I did all steps finally am getting this error

```
sudo service solr start

Waiting up to 30 seconds to see Solr running on port 8983 [/]  Still not seeing Solr listening on 8983 after 30 seconds!
tail: cannot open ‘/var/solr/logs/solr.log’ for reading: No such file or directory
```

I created the  touch solr.log file. but will start the solr log file is removed.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on my vagrant box. It's gone when I raised my vb.memory in Vagrantfile to 1024:

```
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     # Customize the amount of memory on the VM:
     vb.memory = "1024"
   end
```